# How to get the first column of an 1D array that has many sets/dictionaries in each row

Tags: dataframe, pymoo

I have from pymoo:

```
variables=all_pop.get("X")
```

and it gets an output an nd.array that looks like that:

```
{'x0': 21, 'x1': 52, 'x2': 7}
{'x0': 85, 'x1': 18, 'x2': 4}
{'x0': 15, 'x1': 30, 'x2': 6}
{'x0': 22, 'x1': 58, 'x2': 7}
```

When I tried to take the first element of each column using

```
variables = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(all_pop.get("X")[:,0])))
```

I had an error that said "IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed".

How to create a pandas data frame that will print to excel like that?

| x0 | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 52 | 7 |
| 85 | 18 | 4 |
| 15 | 30 | 6 |
| 22 | 58 | 7 |